# python and gtk3 clipboard onChange

Tags: python, clipboard, gtk3

With PyGTK 2 I could attach a function to be executed when the contents of the clipboard was changed. Browsing through the documentation of GTK3's python bindings I can not find any description of such an functionality.

Can anyone tell me the 'best practice' for this?

**EDIT**

With gtk2 the following works:

```
import gtk

def test(*args):
  print "Clipboard changed"

clip = gtk.Clipboard()
clip.connect('owner-change',test)
```

When adopting to Gtk3

```
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk

def test(*args):
  print "Clipboard changed"

clip = Gtk.Clipboard.get(Gdk.SELECTION_CLIPBOARD)
clip.Connect('owner-change',test)
```

Python accepts the connection to the signal, but my function is never executed.

Comment: What signal was that in PyGTK? I don't know of it.

Comment: I could use the signal 'owner-change'. clipboard.connect accepts the signal even in GTK3, but the function I attach is never called.

Comment: The documentation of that signal says it is fired when the owner of the clipboard selection is changed. Not when the contents are changed. If you're going to rely on undocumented behavior, then you have to expect it to break.

Comment: I realise that, which is why I asked for the 'best practice' to get this functionality.

Comment: Interesting question. The "owner-change" is obviously the wrong signal but I couldn't say what the right solution is.

Answer (score 3):

```
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk

def test(*args):
    print "Clipboard changed"

clip = Gtk.Clipboard.get(Gdk.SELECTION_CLIPBOARD)
clip.connect('owner-change',test)
Gtk.main()
```

works for me.

Comment: Strange! It works now, I must have had some kind of strange setup in my environment. However, Is the 'Owner-change' signal intended for this?